# Add to cmake search path

Tags: cmake, eigen3, cmake-modules

I am compiling a cmake file[1] that needs a common library[2]. How do you tell cmake where to find `FindXXXX.cmake`?

More concretely, cmake runs `find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)` and gets angry because I haven't sent `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` or `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. Given the `path/to/FindEigen3.cmake`, how should they be set? I have set both of these variables to the full qualified path.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:298 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindEigen3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" with any
  of the following names:

    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

[1] The exact file is at https://github.com/lightvector/KataGo/blob/master/cpp/CMakeLists.txt#L298

[2] The exact library is Eigen3, but I suspect the answer does not depend on this fact.

A minimal reproducible example is:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/lightvector/KataGo.git
cd KataGo/cpp
cmake . -DUSE_BACKEND=EIGEN
```

Comment: Search procedure of config files (Eigen provides a config file, not a Find module file) is explained here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#config-mode-search-procedure.

Comment: But basically you fill `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` with install prefix of external libraries. Install prefix means full qualified path of the parent folder of include & lib folders of the installed library (and usually config file is under `lib/cmake/<libname>` folder, so CMake is happy).